# Android SocketTimeoutException reasons

Tags: android, rest, api-design

I would like to use a REST API in my application. It throw `SocketTimeoutException` for all my requests from this app.

`Logcat` output: (You can see this also with pretty formatting here: http://pastebin.com/FbZU6wRd)

> 04-14 18:58:46.769 22839-22839/kovacsdev.hu.facec W/AsyncHttpClient:
>   Passed contentType will be ignored because HttpEntity sets content
>   type 04-14 18:58:46.769 22839-22839/kovacsdev.hu.facec D/dalvikvm:
>   create interp thread : stack size=32KB 04-14 18:58:46.770
>   22839-22839/kovacsdev.hu.facec D/dalvikvm: create new thread 04-14
>   18:58:46.770 22839-22839/kovacsdev.hu.facec D/dalvikvm: new thread
>   created 04-14 18:58:46.770 22839-22839/kovacsdev.hu.facec D/dalvikvm:
>   update thread list 04-14 18:58:46.770 22839-23323/kovacsdev.hu.facec
>   D/dalvikvm: threadid=20: interp stack at 0x53f36000 04-14 18:58:46.770
>   22839-23323/kovacsdev.hu.facec D/dalvikvm: threadid=20: created from
>   interp 04-14 18:58:46.770 22839-22839/kovacsdev.hu.facec D/dalvikvm:
>   start new thread 04-14 18:58:46.771 22839-23323/kovacsdev.hu.facec
>   D/dalvikvm: threadid=20: notify debugger 04-14 18:58:46.771
>   22839-23323/kovacsdev.hu.facec D/dalvikvm: threadid=20
>   (pool-2-thread-1): calling run() 04-14 18:58:46.797
>   22839-22839/kovacsdev.hu.facec I/SurfaceTextureClient:
>   [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x50c8b858) fps:0.30, dur:6595.54,
>   max:6086.69, min:508.85 04-14 18:58:46.797
>   22839-22839/kovacsdev.hu.facec I/SurfaceTextureClient:
>   [STC::queueBuffer] this:0x50c8b858, api:1, last queue time
>   elapsed:6086.69 04-14 18:58:47.154 22839-23323/kovacsdev.hu.facec
>   D/libc-netbsd: getaddrinfo: api.kairos.com get result from proxy >>
>   04-14 18:58:47.155 22839-23323/kovacsdev.hu.facec I/System.out:
>   propertyValue:true 04-14 18:58:47.156 22839-23323/kovacsdev.hu.facec
>   I/System.out: [socket][0] connection
>   /50.17.167.207:80;LocalPort=55439(10000) 04-14 18:58:47.157
>   22839-23323/kovacsdev.hu.facec I/System.out:
>   [CDS]connect[/50.17.167.207:80] tm:10 04-14 18:58:47.158
>   22839-23323/kovacsdev.hu.facec D/Posix: [Posix_connect Debug]Process
>   kovacsdev.hu.facec :80  04-14 18:58:47.158
>   22839-23323/kovacsdev.hu.facec I/System.out:
>   [socket][/192.168.199.102:55439] connected 04-14 18:58:47.158
>   22839-23323/kovacsdev.hu.facec I/System.out: [CDS]rx timeout:10000
>   04-14 18:58:47.159 22839-23323/kovacsdev.hu.facec W/System.err: rto
>   value is too small:0 04-14 18:58:47.164 22839-23323/kovacsdev.hu.facec
>   I/System.out: >doSendRequest 04-14 18:58:47.167
>   22839-22847/kovacsdev.hu.facec D/jdwp: processIncoming 04-14
>   18:58:47.167 22839-22847/kovacsdev.hu.facec D/jdwp: handlePacket :
>   cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x4000013E, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
>   04-14 18:58:47.167 22839-22847/kovacsdev.hu.facec D/jdwp:
>   sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34 04-14 18:58:47.254
>   22839-23323/kovacsdev.hu.facec I/System.out:

Here happens the exact problem.

> 04-14 18:58:57.248 22839-23323/kovacsdev.hu.facec I/System.out:
>   [CDS]EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK in Recvfrom 04-14 18:58:57.249
>   22839-23323/kovacsdev.hu.facec I/System.out: [CDS]read byte is 0 04-14
>   18:58:57.250 22839-23323/kovacsdev.hu.facec I/System.out:
>   [CDS]close[55439] 04-14 18:58:57.251 22839-23323/kovacsdev.hu.facec
>   I/System.out: close [socket][/0.0.0.0:55439] 04-14 18:58:57.252
>   22839-23323/kovacsdev.hu.facec I/System.out:
>   ex:java.net.SocketTimeoutException 04-14 18:58:57.253
>   22839-23323/kovacsdev.hu.facec W/System.err:
>   java.net.SocketTimeoutException 04-14 18:58:57.268
>   22839-23323/kovacsdev.hu.facec W/System.err:     at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:495)

Code snippet:

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file);
        String subjectId = user;
        String galleryId = "users";
        String selector = "FULL";
        String multipleFaces = "false";
        String minHeadScale = "0.25";
        try {
            myKairos.enroll(image,
                    subjectId,
                    galleryId,
                    selector,
                    multipleFaces,
                    minHeadScale,
                    listener);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Method from `Kairos` class.

```
/*
 * Enroll subject into gallery (Image)
 */
public void enroll(Bitmap image,
                   String subjectId,
                   String galleryId,
                   String selector,
                   String multipleFaces,
                   String minHeadScale,
                   final KairosListener callback)  throws JSONException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

    AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler = new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            // called before request is started
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {
            // called when response HTTP status is "200 OK"
            String responseString = new String(response);
            callback.onSuccess(responseString);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] errorResponse, Throwable e) {
            // called when response HTTP status is "4XX" (eg. 401, 403, 404)
            String responseString = new String(errorResponse);
            callback.onFail(responseString);

        }

        @Override
        public void onRetry(int retryNo) {
            // called when request is retried
        }

    };

    JSONObject jsonParams = new JSONObject();
    jsonParams.put("image", base64FromBitmap(image));
    jsonParams.put("subject_id", subjectId);
    jsonParams.put("gallery_name", galleryId);

    if(selector != null) {
        jsonParams.put("selector", selector);
    }

    if(minHeadScale != null) {
        jsonParams.put("minHeadScale", minHeadScale);
    }

    if(multipleFaces != null) {
        jsonParams.put("multiple_faces", multipleFaces);
    }

    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jsonParams.toString());
    client.addHeader("app_id", my_app_id);
    client.addHeader("app_key", my_api_key);
    client.post(my_context, "http://api.kairos.com/enroll", entity, "application/json", responseHandler);

}
```

Comment: There is no SocketTimeOutException in the log here. Post relevant pieces of your LogCat in a code block here please and show your code.

Comment: @greenapps: Information added.

Comment: Please post the logcat in a code block too. So we can see the lines.

Comment: There is nothing in the code you posted that has anything to do with sockets. Nothing that can produce that exception. Why do you post irrelevant code? Come to the point please. Do you think we know `myKairos` ?

Comment: @greenapps : Sorry, I have posted code, which gives more information.

Comment: `PlainSocketImpl.java:495`. Post more of that LogCat please. Until a java file is mentionend that you programmed. Then also tell which code is on that line. Can you please put the log in a -grey- code block? Not in a yellow block.

Comment: DId you request INTERNET permission in manifest file?

Comment: Log was posted earlier in grey, but someone have edited it.
No Java files of mine are mentioned in the log.
Internet access is already defined in manifest,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a Static Http Client as recomended here http://loopj.com/android-async-http/, but also pass the context to the get/post methods.

Comment: Seems good, but you can see above, that I couldn't make that because of this approach.